# JavaScript - Get size from class name and open new window

Tags: javascript, html

For a long time, I have been using a simple JavaScript file along with in-line, onclick events in 'a' tags to open a new window when the link is clicked. As you can see from the example below, I add the type and size of the window in the HTML. In the example below, the window cannot be resized by the user, is centered and is 1010 wide by 730 high.

**Example HTML:**

```
<a href="https://example.com" target='_blank' onclick="popUp(this.href,'elasticNoC',1010,730);return false;">
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
var newWin = null;
    function popUp(strURL, strType, strWidth, strHeight) {
    LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-strWidth)/2 : 0;
    TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-strHeight)/2 : 0;
     if (newWin !== null && !newWin.closed)
       newWin.close();
     var strOptions="";
     if (strType=="consoleC")
       strOptions="resizable,top="+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+",height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
     if (strType=="fixedC")
       strOptions="status,top="+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+",height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
     if (strType=="elasticC")
       strOptions="toolbar,menubar,scrollbars,"+
         "resizable,location,top="+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+",height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
    if (strType=="elasticNoC")
       strOptions="scrollbars,"+
         "resizable,top="+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+",height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
    if (strType=="console")
       strOptions="resizable,height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
     if (strType=="fixed")
       strOptions="status,height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
     if (strType=="elastic")
       strOptions="toolbar,menubar,scrollbars,"+
         "resizable,location,height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
    if (strType=="elasticNo")
       strOptions="scrollbars,"+
         "resizable,height="+
         strHeight+",width="+strWidth;
     newWin = window.open(strURL, 'newWin', strOptions);
     newWin.focus();
    }
```

A recent update of a web application is now stripping in-line JavaScript so my old way of doing things no longer works.

I can still include separate JavaScript files but no in-line JavaScript.

I am thinking that the best option is to replace the in-line, onclick events with specific class names and use JavaScript to get the window type and size from the class name.

**Example new HTML:**

```
<a class="red elasticNoC-1010-730" href="https://example.com" target="_blank">
```

I can't figure out the correct JavaScript to use. Can someone please provide JavaScript code that can be used as a replacement? As you can see in the new HTML example, some of my links may contain more than one class name. In this example, the class name "red" would be ignored because it does not match any of the 'strType' in the JavaScript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use classes, use `data-*` attribute:

```
<a class="red" data-popup="elasticNoC-1010-730" href="https://example.com" target="_blank">TEST CLICK</a>
```

and than the JS would be like:

```js
// var newWin = null; function popUp( ............etc


const handlePopup = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();                       // Prevent browser default action
  const EL = ev.currentTarget;               // Get the element
  const args = EL.dataset.popup.split("-");  // Get the data-* parts
  args.unshift(EL.getAttribute("href"));     // Prepend HREF to parts
  return popUp(...args);                     // Call popUp with arguments
};

const EL_popup = document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup]');
EL_popup.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handlePopup));
```

[image]

### Handling classes

Handling classes for custom attributes values is never a great idea, since it mostly becomes a parsing-things problem, because HTML attribute `class` can contain a multitude of classes in any order and number.

**But luckily** you could create a specific **prefixed classname** (with `popUp-`) like

```html
    popUp-elasticNoC-1010-730
```

and than use that specific prefix as your reference for splitting the specific string parts of interest, but also as your Elements selector:

```
querySelectorAll('[class*=" popUp-"], [class^="popUp-"]')
```

Here's an example:

```js
const handlePopup = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();                         // Prevent browser default action
  const EL = ev.currentTarget;                 // Get the element
  const classPopUp = [...EL.classList].filter(cl => cl.startsWith("popUp-"))[0];
  const args = classPopUp.split('-');          // Convert class item to array    
  args.shift();                                // remove "popUp-" prefix
  args.unshift(EL.getAttribute("href"));       // Prepend HREF to parts
  return popUp(...args);                       // Call popUp with arguments
};

const EL_popup = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=" popUp-"], [class^="popUp-"]');
EL_popup.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handlePopup));
```

```html
<a class="red popUp-elasticNoC-1010-730 foo-bar" href="https://example.com" target="_blank">TEST CLICK</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your example! Unfortunately, the web app is also stripping data attributes. It seems the only option I have is to use classes. Can you tweak your example to use classes?

Comment: @Jeff may I know what "web-app" we're talking about?

Comment: ConnectWise Control.

Comment: @Jeff have no idea what you're up to, but added what you asked.

Comment: Thank you! They must have changed a lot because I cannot get it to work with ConnectWise Control. Your example does work on a separate test page that I created so you answered my question.